# WHERE clause in a SQL statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to define two conditions for a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE Date = @date (already implemented)
and
WHERE Type = @currenttype
```

Code as follows:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT Result FROM {0} WHERE Date = @date", hostnameclear);
```

Would I use two `WHERE` clauses, or can I specify two conditions?

Comment: `WHERE Date = @date AND Type = @currenttype` Are you kidding?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Yes, why yes I am, you have got me! ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT Result FROM {0} WHERE Date = @date and Type = @currenttype
```

**just remove second "Where" will do you task**

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two `WHERE` clauses.

This is correct:

```
WHERE Date = @date
AND Type = @currenttype
```

I would urge you to use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead of `string.Format`, as you are opening your code up to [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

This is still possible to do with [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) (seeing as you are specifying the table name, dynamic SQL is probably required).

Comment: Security-wise, I don't see a difference between string concatenation on the client (current solution) and string concatenation on the server (dynamic SQL)...

Comment: @Heinzi - If you pass in the string to concatenate in a parameter, you get some extra protection.

Comment: How so? If I pass Bobby tables into `EXEC('SELECT Result FROM ' + @tblname)`, I can execute arbitrary statements, *even though* user input was provided through a parameter.

Comment: @Heinzi - `@tblname` would contain sanitized values. If you only have table names < 20 characters and you define `@tblname VARCHAR(20)`, you already limit the exposure. Quotes will be escaped as well.

Comment: True, limiting the string size would improve security, although that could be done in C# as well -- just like sanitizing inputs; either way, the developer has to implement it. About the quotes: Why do you think that they are automatically escaped?

Comment: @Heinzi - In parameterized queries? The provider would do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7518/discussion-between-heinzi-and-oded)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second `WHERE` clause: the following statements fall within that context, you would join them with `AND`, and the next clause would start with the next command, say `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
where data = @data AND somecolumn = issomething.
```

one where with "and" statements.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Result FROM {0} WHERE Date = @date AND Type = @type
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have one where statement.

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT Result FROM {0} WHERE Date = @date AND Type = @currenttype", hostnameclear);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice when you program in C#, Java, Perl whatever is to ensure that your sql syntax is correct by using commandline tools like sqlplus or any other sql prompt. 
This helps a lot for this kind of errors.